# app framework2.0 include jquery can't use the $.ui.loadContent()

Tags: jqmobi

`< script src='jquery.js'></script><script src='jq.appframework.js'></script><script　src='appframework.ui.js'></script>`

`<a onclick="$.ui.loadContent('uiapi',false,false,'flip')" class="button">Load $.ui API page with a flip</a>`

I can't click the button,and a problem like this:'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined '

Answer (score 0):

Guessing it's an id your calling (note the hash)

```
<a onclick="$.ui.loadContent('#uiapi',false,false,'flip')" class="button">Load $.ui API page with a flip</a>
```